How detect position:sticky is triggered when target element is not on top:0 position
I've already use this solution with IntersectionObserver (top:-1px  + IntersectionObserver ), but it works only if target sticky element initially positioned as top: 0
But in my case - I have two sticky elements with different top position and sticked together later: How to do the same trick with sticky detection for nav element also?
This is example how I've do the stuff with header element for now


    // header sticky detection hack
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
    ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle("is-sticky", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
    { 
        threshold: [1] }
    );
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('header'));

    // how to do that with nav element also?
    // I've tried to create other observer with reduced viewport bounds (rootMargin = 72px)
    const observerNav = new IntersectionObserver( 
    ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle("is-sticky", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
    {
      rootMargin: '72px 0px 0px 0px',
      threshold: [1]
     }
    );
    observerNav.observe(document.querySelector('nav'));
body {
   min-height: 800px;
   background-color: #eee;
}

.styled {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
header {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 72px;
    position: sticky;
    top:-1px; /* trick */
}
header.is-sticky {
   background: yellow;
}
.hero {
    height: 100px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
}
nav {
   background: #bbb;
   height: 36px;
   position: sticky;
   top: 72px;
   top: 71px; /* trick attempt */
   width: 100%;
}
/* just for example */
nav.is-sticky {
   background: green;
}
<header class="styled">HEADER</header>
<div class="hero styled">SOME CONTENT</div>
<nav class="styled">NAVIGATION</nav>



